# Instantly call loadObjects() method inside a ContainerView

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I have the following situation:

**View A** - Is a view that contains a form to create comments and also a ContainerView to View B

**View B** - Is a view that contains a tableView that lists the comments created by View A

Since the user creates the comments on View A while it sees the View B.

I would like to be able to instantly call loadObjects() methods inside View B from View A and reload the content on View B

Is it something that can be achieved?

[image]